# How can I keep my button/rivet fly jeans closed?

Tags: clothing

When reading "[Ηow can I keep my jeans' zippers from unzipping on their own?](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/q/123/4490)", I remembered having a pair of jeans with buttons or rivets instead of a zipper, and that these always came undone. And fixing that, is kind of uncomfortable.

So, how can I keep the rivet fly or button jeans closed up?

Comment: They still make button-fly pants???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a couple of stitches in each buttonhole to make it a little smaller - check you're not making them too small so the button or stud won't go through, but you need to have them so its reasonably tough to push through the hole.

Answer (score 2):

Glue a thin leather disk to the inside of the part with the hole and make a slit in it by pushing the tip of a sharp knife through the buttonhole, **DO NOT DO THIS WHILE WEARING THE JEANS!**